# how to find common columns between 2 data set in r?

Tags: r, subset

I have two data sets: "datExprSTLMS" which its dimension is 53*17237 and "datExprSTF" which its dimension is 99*22144. In two data sets, some columns(gene_names) are common. Based on using match() between colnames of two data sets I have founded 15711(TRUE) gene_name as intersecting genes between them. Now, I would like to provide a subset of "datExprSTLMS" so that the dimension of "datExprSTLMS" will be 53*15711. For this purpose I wrote below code:

```
 dim(datExprSTF)
 #[1]    99 22144

 dim(datExprSTLMS)
 #[1]    53 17237

 TCGA2STF <- match(colnames(datExprSTLMS), colnames(datExprSTF))
 table(is.finite(TCGA2STF))
 #FALSE  TRUE 
 #1526  15711 

 #delete NA(mismatch gene_names which in my case are 1526)
 TCGA2STF_final <- Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x)), TCGA2STF)

 datExprSTLMS_final <- as.data.frame(datExprSTLMS[,TCGA2STF_final])
```

but after running the last line of my code I get below Error:

```
 Error in datExprSTLMS[, TCGA2STF_final] : subscript out of bounds
```

I write my code in the R language. I need to guide

Comment: Do you need `datExprSTLMS[, intersect(colnames(datExprSTLMS), colnames(datExprSTF))]` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `intersect` to find common columns between two data sets and then use them to subset `datExprSTLMS`

```
datExprSTLMS[, intersect(colnames(datExprSTLMS), colnames(datExprSTF))]
```